# Why a analytic function must fail to be analytic somewhere on its radius on convergence.

Tags: complex-analysis

my book wrote this:

[image]

It says that the function must fail to be analytic somewhere on the circle of convergence. Is this a correct way of proving that this must hold, and is there also a simpler reason why they may say this?

Assume for contradiction that the function is analytic on the entire circle. By **definition(?)** that means that on every point on the circle of convergence there is a small open circle where the function is analytic. Since the circle of convergence is a compact set, we look at we must have a minimum radius of these small covering circles which is larger than zero(call it $r_{small}$, by the extreme value theorem. If we now cover each point on the circle of convergence with these small circles, then we see that  that we can extend the original radius R with $r_{small}/2$.

Is this proof correct? The reason I chose to divide with 2 was that when we move along the circle of convergence and cover each point by a circle with radius $r_{small}$ is it really that obvious that the the area we cover have a radius $R+r_{small}$? Or could some points inside the circle of radius $+r_{small}$ be missing?

Comment: Your argument shows that $f$ would be analytic on a larger disk. This does not immediatly show that the Taylor series converges in this larger disk (but it is true and possibly contained in what your quote summarizes)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If I use Cauchys integral formula, and inside the integral change the denominator with an appropritae geometric series I get a power series. And then if I use that this power series must be the Taylor series, am I done then?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true!

Take the function
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n(n-1)(n-2)}.
$$
Then,

a. Its radius of convergence is $r=1$.

b. The power series converges if and only if $\,\lvert z\rvert\le 1$.

c. It defines a continuous function in the closed unit disk.

d. It is differentiable even on the boundary of the unit disk!